# The smallest singular value of a bi-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that the smallest singular value of matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & &  & \\ 
 & 1 & 2 &  &  \\ 
 &  & ... &  & \\ 
 &  &  & 1 & 2\\ 
 &  &  &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}$

is less or equal $2^{1 - n}$ (without calculation, if it is possible). Please help, i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $A$ be the matrix in the question, and let $$x = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{4} & \cdots & (-\tfrac{1}{2})^{n-2} & (-\tfrac{1}{2})^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}^T.$$

Then, compute $\|Ax\|_2$ and $\|x\|_2$. What does this tell you about the smallest singular value?

Comment: Now i understand, thank you!